# Organizing VB.Net Mehods

Tags: vb.net, organization

Say I have a class with several methods within it. I want to organize the methods into groupings that can be accessed without constructing a new object each time. The purpose is to group the methods of the class into logical buckets

For instance:

```
Dim myclass as MyCustomClass
myclass.Shipping.Get_List()
myclass.Production.Get_List()
```

What is the best way to do this? I tried nested classes, but VB.NET won't let me access the methods as shown above.

Comment: You may be able to do it with a nested class if the parent class has a (possibly `Shared`) instance of that class as a public member.  Though, to be honest, this doesn't really sound like a good idea.  It's very unconventional and unintuitive, which makes the code that much more difficult to support.  And if you're trying to find a way to intuitively group methods in your class then it sounds like the class needs some re-factoring into possibly multiple classes.

Comment: I actually clarified the example as you wrote your comment. The purpose is that there are different groups of methods affecting sub-categories. For example "Shipping" has a slew of methods for that category. I was originally going to separate them into different classes, but there were overlaps and some common variables that they all rely upon. It seemed more intuitive to keep it as one structure since they are all interfacing to the same underlying data.

Comment: "overlaps and some common variables" sounds like a case for multiple polymorphic classes, not one large class that tries to cater to everything.  Also, the structure of the classes doesn't necessarily have to match the structure of the underlying data.  Very often that is the case, but the two should not be tightly coupled with one another.  The very nature of object oriented classes vs. relational data has a tendency to differ in representation of the same concepts.  Knowing nothing about the code, I can only recommend reading up on design patterns and object oriented design.

Answer (score 0):

so this is how i would do what you want

this is not the best design of the world but it would work

I would suggest you to move the actual get_list and other kind of method / property into the specific class while keeping the common one in the parent class, which in this case is test

but then, I have no idea what your code look like so from that point on, it's your choice

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim test As New test
        test.Production.Get_List()
        test.Shipping.Get_List()
    End Sub

End Module


Public Class Shipping
    Private parent As test

    Public Sub New(ByRef parent As test)
        Me.parent = parent
    End Sub

    Public Function Get_List() As List(Of Integer)
        Return parent.GetShipping_List
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Production
    Private parent As test

    Public Sub New(ByRef parent As test)
        Me.parent = parent
    End Sub

    Public Function Get_List() As List(Of Integer)
        Return parent.GetProduction_List
    End Function
End Class

Public Class test
    Public Property Production As Production
    Public Property Shipping As Shipping


    Public Function GetShipping_List() As List(Of Integer)
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Function GetProduction_List() As List(Of Integer)
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Sub New()
        Production = New Production(Me)
        Shipping = New Shipping(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the approach I'm looking for. The reason for this approach is that I need a single interface point which others will interact with. They are not able to see the underlying structure, and all of the subsections "Shipping", "Production", etc must co-exist. For those reasons it didn't make sense to me to have the user instance several different classes. Your approach makes sense since it does that in the background and still gives the end-user the appearance of a single interface.

Answer (score 0):

With caution that you more than likely should re-evaluate your architecture, you could implement your pattern like this:

```
Public Class MyCustomClass
    Private _shippingList As List(Of String)
    Private _productionList As List(Of String)

    Public Production As ProductionClass
    Public Shipping As ShippingClass

    Public Sub New()
        Production = New ProductionClass(Me)
        Shipping = New ShippingClass(Me)
    End Sub

    Public Class ShippingClass
        Private _owner As MyCustomClass

        Public Sub New(owner As MyCustomClass)
            _owner = owner
        End Sub

        Public Function Get_List()
            Return _owner._productionList
        End Function
    End Class

    Public Class ProductionClass
        Private _owner As MyCustomClass

        Public Sub New(owner As MyCustomClass)
            _owner = owner
        End Sub

        Public Function Get_List()
            Return _owner._productionList
        End Function
    End Class

End Class
```

However, if your true intent is simply organizing the methods in a more accessible and logical manner, I would suggest considering:

```
Public Class MyCustomClass
    Public Sub ShippingListGet()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ShippingListAddTo()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ShippingThatDO()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ShippingThisDo()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ProductionListGet()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ProductionListAddTo()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ProductionThisDo()
    End Sub

    Public Sub ProductionThatDo()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Keep in mind, some people consider that difficult to read. I personally prefer organization along those lines so when the methods are sorted alphabetically they group logically.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution I was looking for using interfaces

```
Public Interface ICompany
    Function Company_List() As DataTable
End Interface

Public Class MainClass
    Public Company As ICompany = New CompanyClass

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Private Class CompanyClass
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub

        Public Function Company_List() As DataTable
              My code....
        End Function
End Class
End Class
```